# Directive Scope always empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cobo3wzu/1/)

```
app.directive('rateClass', function() {
    function link ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        var className = '';
        if($scope.ranking > 9)
            className = 'ranked-excelent';
        else if($scope.ranking > 6)
            className = 'ranked-good';
        else if($scope.ranking > 3)
            className = 'ranked-regular';
        else if($scope.ranking > 0)
            className = 'ranked-bad';

        console.log($scope, className);
    };

    return {
        scope: {
            rank: '='
        },
        restrict: 'AEC',
        link: link
    };
});
```

My directive Works, in deed it executes the link function, but the variable className Doesn't get filled, even though $scope get the rank attribute (checking console.log), when I access to it `$scope.rank` returns an empty string.

What's happening here?

**update**

See full [demo](http://diggi.duckdns.org:8000/#/detalles/alejox)

**update 2** Solved with this

```
app.directive('rateClass', function() {
    var getClass = function (val) {
        var className = 'not-ranked';
        if(val > 9)
            className = 'ranked-excelent';
        else if(val > 6)
            className = 'ranked-good';
        else if(val > 3)
            className = 'ranked-regular';
        else if(val > 0)
            className = 'ranked-bad';
        return className;
    }

    function link ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.$watch($attrs.score, function (value) {
            $element.addClass(getClass(value));
        })
    };

    return {
        link: link
    };
});
```

Comment: You're violating the . rule here. See here: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html

Comment: please provide the html code using this directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo, you used `$scope.ranking` instead of `$scope.rank`

```
function link ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    var className = '';
    if($scope.rank > 9)
        className = 'ranked-excelent';
    else if($scope.rank > 6)
        className = 'ranked-good';
    else if($scope.rank > 3)
        className = 'ranked-regular';
    else if($scope.rank > 0)
        className = 'ranked-bad';

    console.log($scope, className);
};
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cobo3wzu/2/

**NOTE**: in the full demo version you put in your edit, you should put:

```
    $scope.$watch('score', function (value) {
        value = parseFloat(value) || 0;
        $element.addClass(getClass(value));
    })
```

instead of:

```
    $scope.$watch($attrs.score, function (value) {
        value = parseFloat(value) || 0;
        $element.addClass(getClass(value));
    })
```

This is because, in the directory you have the `score` property binded to the `scope`. By checking `$attrs.score`, you are actually checking this result: `"local.promedio_general"`

Comment: Still, when i write it to the full demo doesn't work, I'll put an online demo

Answer (score 1):

You're defining the scope property to be `rank` but in your link function you are referencing a variable named `ranking`